# Prove that the area of a triangle DEF is correct.

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

There's any triangle ABC. First player 1 has to set D on AB so that in the end the triangle DEF has the highest possible area. Second player 2 has to set E on BC so that in the end the triangle has the lowest possible area. And third player 1 has to set F on CA so that in the end the triangle has the highest possible area. Question: What is the area of DEF? Task 2: Prove that the answer for the question is correct. 
I think the area of DEF is one quarter of the area of ABC but I have not found a way to mathematically prove that this answer is correct.

Comment: This seems contradictory; $D$ and $F$ are placed to maximize area, but $E$ is supposed to minimize area?

Comment: Think of it as a game. One player wants to minimize area the other one wants to maximize it.

Comment: Ah, ok. You might want to edit your question to clarify that.

Comment: Also, if we're just talking about two-dimensional triangles, we just use "area"; surface area comes in once we move to three or more dimensions.

Comment: I edited the question.